# Way to add custom class when using ngx-bootstrap modalService

Tags: css, angular, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-modal

When looking to the [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/) [*source code*](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap) here:

[**modal-options.class.ts**](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/src/modal/modal-options.class.ts)

There is an optional `class property` defined as `class?: string;`.

What is the way to use it ?

Is it possible to add a custom class like:

```
this.modalService.config.class = 'myClass';
```

Before using the servive as for example:

```
this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, {
  animated: false
});
```

This way, I think we can add custom CSS to the displayed modal

I've tried to add a custom class without success.

That class property is not an array, if applicable, does it mean that we can only add one custom class ?

**Demo:** by adding and overriding the `modal` class, the modal is not showing

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-3auk5l?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Adding the `modal` class this way do not help:

```
this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, Object.assign({},
                this.config, { class: 'gray modal-lg modal' }));
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-awmkrc?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I moved your CSS from the *app.component.css* to the *styles.css* and I see something different. Have you tried that?

Comment: where is that css ? you cannot modify the above demo link, you may try to fork it before.

Comment: Try this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-tibwjk?file=app%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: probably interesting, but already saw that here: https://plnkr.co/edit/NJRvUMZN2kHZruFgeOjQ?p=preview, in one of my questions, looks same but it could be better when having to add that in a complex app to get each component with its proper css. not sure if it’s only the way we can implement it at this point.

Comment: I just added the justify and align to the stackblitz styles.css I was playing with.. dead center. Looks good. Do you have all you need now?

Comment: it would be better if we have something like **top:50%;left:50%** or **    justify-content: center; align-items: center;** that's why I feel that there is some improvements, but will try that in a real app. the `modal` class may interfere with other part of the app ... bootstrap or anything else because its a global style as configured. but will see

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the ngx-bootstrap [documentation](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-options) about the Modal component (see the *component* tab), you can add a `class` member to the config object.

**Important**: Since the modal element is outside of the component element in the rendered HTML, the CSS encapsulation should be turned off for the component, or the style attributes for the class should be specified in another file, to make sure that the styles are applied to the modal element.

The code snippet below can be executed in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-mjcjnz).

```
import { Component, TemplateRef, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent {
  modalRef: BsModalRef;
  config = {
    animated: true,
    keyboard: true,
    backdrop: true,
    ignoreBackdropClick: false,
    class: "my-modal"
  };

  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) { }

  openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, this.config);
  }
}
```

with a CSS file like this:

```
.my-modal {
  border: solid 4px blue;
}

.my-modal .modal-header {
  background-color: lime;
}

.my-modal .modal-body {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

**Update**: This [other stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-3erfzm) shows an example of CSS styles imported from an external file into `styles.css`, allowing to keep the CSS encapsulation in the component.

Comment: OK, but as you see it is not easy to get a working example for that library, I'm looking for a concrete example, because all those modals are not showing centered, I'm trying to do that, when you try to add a live style in dev tools where you have the `modal` class, you can get a little bit the modal in the center, but unfortunately there is no concrete example about this

Comment: I modified your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-mjcjnz) to make the CSS styling work for the class `my-class`. I only applied colors but you can get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the effort you made, `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` can probably create some styling problems for the component where I have to add the template to, probably I'll consider then creating a modal component apart to see. will do some tests and give value and some feedback for the answer later.

Comment: An alternative would be to define the style attributes for the class `my-modal` in a separate CSS file and simply import it in the code file: `import "./modal-class.style.css";`.

Comment: ConnorsFan: in the answer, can you add a `stackblitz` link where you remove `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` and adding a css file to get the same result ?

Comment: @HDJEMAI - I added the other [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-3erfzm) to the answer. The file `modal-styles.css` is imported in `styles.css` and the encapsulation is kept in the component.

Comment: Thanks! Awesome answer :)