# How to add custom css to ngx-bootstrap modal with modalService useage(see reasons below)?

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-modal, ngx-bootstrap

I have a very niche use-case. I have to add a modal animation like this:
[regular css animation](https://codepen.io/bootpen/pen/jbbaRa)
But I need to have a component (our own filter component for a datatable) inside said modal.
So I need to use the ModalService. But this service is only attaching my custom config like this:

```
  toggleFilter = () => {
    const modalOptions: ModalOptions = {
      initialState: {
        labels: this.datatableLabels, // needed for filter to have labels
        filterGroups: this.filterGroups // needed to add filterGroups
      },
      class: 'filter-modal' // this sould be my custom class
    };
    this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(FilterComponent, modalOptions);
  }
```

to `modal-content` and the above mentioned animation and styling uses divs above that. Not only it's working when encapsulation set to`ViewEncapsulation.None` then it screws our other modals as well, since I cannot apply correct classes to the one I need to mess with.

How can I overcome this issue I'm having?

Comment: Try to add css by targeting component selector. May be this will not affect other modules when set ViewEncapsulation.None.

Comment: see [way-to-add-custom-class-when-using-ngx-bootstrap-modalservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47957036/way-to-add-custom-class-when-using-ngx-bootstrap-modalservice)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the ModalService and open desired embedded component within the modal. You can basically inject the desired component into the body of the modal while using directive instead -> Here you are declaring the whole modal layout -> you can modify all the related classes so it's easier to modify a modal and have your ViewEncapsulation untuched so other modals are unaffected.